# How to convert flattened SQL Table to Rows (approximately UNPIVOTting)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot, flatten

Imagine the source table schema:

```
Table1: ID*, ValueA, ValueB, ValueX1, ValueX2, ValueX3, ValueY1, ValueY2, ValueY3
```

And the destination table Schema:

```
TableA: ID*, ValueA, ValueB
TableB: ID*, Type*, Value1, Value2, Value3
```

Where a single row in `Table1` is represented by 1 row in `TableA` and 2 rows in `TableB` (One with Type `X`, the other with Type `Y`)

---

*Yes, the existence of the former schema makes me sad. No, I didn't write it. No, I can't directly change it. :(*

---

I want to right a query to convert `Table1` into `TableB` (obviously, getting `TableA` is easy.)

I know how to do this with a `UNION ALL`, but that's going to be ugly. (Not least because `(X,Y)` is actually `(P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)`, and `1 ... 3` is actually `1 ... 15`. Sigh)

I feel like `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` are sort of vaguely close, but I can't see anything that specifically deals with this - I always see something that's only moving single columns, or sets of single columns.

**Can this be done elegantly, in T-SQL, in any sense?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this

`Cross Apply` method:(preferred)

```
SELECT ID, tc.Type, tc.Value1, tc.Value2, tc.Value3
FROM   yourtable
        CROSS apply (VALUES (ValueX1,ValueX2,ValueX3,'X'),
                            (ValueY1,ValueY2,ValueY3,'Y') )tc (Value1, Value2, Value3, Type)
```

`UNION ALL` method

```
SELECT ID,type = 'X',ValueX1,ValueX2,ValueX3
FROM   yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,'Y', ValueY1,ValueY2,ValueY3
FROM   yourtable
```

Note both the approaches consider that, the datatype of `ValueX1` and `ValueY1` is implicitly convertible or same. Same goes to remaining pairs as well

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks. Yes consistency of DataTypes is a requirement. (He says, realising that he hasn't actually checked that it's TRUE, and having literally no faith in the designers of the original schema)